# Github Action docker run step with 'npm run build' exits with 'status code 1' - step still goes forward

Tags: docker, github-actions, status, exit-code

I have a github action file where in a docker run step, I have a npm run build command which no matter if the build fails or succeeds the step still exits with status 0, because the container did its job, is it possible to overwrite the exit code status based on the npm run build outcome?

```
- name: Build
    uses: addnab/docker-run-action@v3
    with:
      image: node
      options: -v ${{ github.workspace }}:/app
      run: |
        cp -rf src/data/Config_TST.js src/data/Config.js
        rm -rf node_modules
        npm install
        npm run build-css
        npm run build --production
        cp -a web.config build/
```

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw out the addnab step and I solved it via manual run of docker run and docker exec commands.